# Python 3.4 unicode: different behaviour on different platforms running Debian

Tags: python, unicode

while developing a Python application which is intended to run on a Raspberry Pi 2 running a Debian Jessie (armhf port) I've observed differences in the handling of unicode between my amd64 port and the RPi:

**Raspberry Pi 2 (model B) with Debian Jessie**

*Linux echo 3.18.0-trunk-rpi2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 3.18.5-1~exp1.co1 (2015-02-02) armv7l GNU/Linux*

```
user@echo:~$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 14:38:51) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import binascii as ba
>>> b="414243FC"
>>> u=ba.unhexlify(b)
>>> u
b'ABC\xfc'
>>> s=u.decode('latin-1')
>>> s
'ABC\xfc'
>>> print(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Same code in an amd64 virtual box with same Python version**
*Linux jessie-vbox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u1 (2015-12-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux*

```
user@jessie-vbox:~$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import binascii as ba
>>> b="414243FC"
>>> u=ba.unhexlify(b)
>>> u
b'ABC\xfc'
>>> s=u.decode('latin-1')
>>> s
'ABCü'
>>> print(s)
ABCü
>>>
```

**Am I missing something or is this a bug? A Debian bug or a Python bug?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have work on similar trouble. I discover that locale are importants on this problem. So try command "locale" to discover some difference on LC_XXX variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emmanuel DUMAS's comment gave me the right clue: indeed, LANG was unset, so the command "locale" showed a lot of "POSIX" entries.

As I don't need locale support (and don't have any other locale configured), I set LANG to "C.UTF-8".